# Solve the following system of equations - (2).

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations, rational-functions

> (a) Solve the following system of equations:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x(x + 1) + \dfrac{1}{y}\left(\dfrac{1}{y} + 1\right) = 4\\
> \dfrac1{y^2}(x+1) + x^2\left(\dfrac{1}{y} + 1\right) = 4
> \end{cases}$$
>   (b) Solve the following system of equations:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x(x + 1) + \dfrac{1}{y}\left(\dfrac{1}{y} + 1\right) = 4\\
> \dfrac{1}{y}(x^2 + 1) + x\left(\dfrac{1}{y^2} + 1\right) = 4
> \end{cases}
> $$

This problem comes from a competition I participated this morning (19/3/2019). And the problems were hard. Out of 11 problems, I only did 7. That counts this one.

Comment: So you managed to solve this problem (it seems like it, from your last sentence)?

Comment: I did manage to solve it. I just want to see another, shorter solution.

Comment: Ah I see. Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks! The next question will be the one that I couldn't do. It's geometry.

Comment: How can we know whether we have a shorter solution than yours, if we don't know yours?

Comment: You don't need to. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: So we might put in a lot of work and then it turns out we've just duplicated what you've already done? No, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will substitute $$y=tx$$ in the second equation, then we get
$$\frac{x}{t^2x^2}+\frac{1}{t^2x^2}+\frac{x^2}{tx}+x^2-4=0$$ and this is

$$(tx^2+2tx+x+1)(tx^2-2tx+1)=0$$ so we get
$$tx^2+2tx+x+1=0$$
or

$$tx^2-2tx+1=0$$
which can be solved for $t$.